# Como deixar o fundo de um input da cor do hover em uma tabela?

Tags: html5, css3, css-hover

Existe alguma maneira de deixar um input que por padrão tem seu background-color branco ficar com a cor da linha no momento do **hover**?

```css
input { border: none; outline: none }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Primeiro</th>
      <th scope="col">Input</th>
      <th scope="col">Nickname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="teste 1"></td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="teste 2"></td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem sim, mas ai o user não vai perceber que o campo é editavel, veja como ficaria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
input { border: none; outline: none }

.table-hover tbody tr:hover input{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Primeiro</th>
      <th scope="col">Input</th>
      <th scope="col">Nickname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="teste 1"></td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="teste 2"></td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Legal @hugocsl , a questão do user eu vou inserir um botão de editar aí quando for clicado eu dou foco no input, sem problemas. Mas, poderia explicar o funcionamento, é tipo setar um fundo preto com opacidade é isso?

Comment: @LeAndrade na verdade não... o que acontece é que essa cor de fundo da TR, é um preto com opacidade, é o padrão do bootstrap, e como eu peguei o estilo direto do CSS do bootstrap a cor veio em RGBA, mas vc pode simplesmente colocar `transparent` ali se quiser. A minha inteção foi não mexer muito com a hierarquia de classe do bootstrap, por isso coloquei a linha completa `.table-hover tbody tr:hover` antes do `input`. Detalhe que até onde eu sei o BS não tem uma classe tipo bg-transparent ou bg-none, então tem que fazer na mão

Comment: Certo, entendi. Valeu @hugocsl.

Comment: @LeAndrade tmj! 